# How can I fix my Function to show different results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-functions

Can someone review my code and guide me what did I do wrong? I managed to create stored function. However, after selecting, the only result for hotellevel is silver.

```
CREATE FUNCTION HotelLevel
(
    @rating DECIMAL(10,2)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @hotel_level VARCHAR(20);

    SELECT @rating = rating
    FROM Hotels;

    IF @rating < 4.10
        SET @hotel_level = 'Blue';    
    ELSE IF (@rating >= 4.10 AND @rating < 4.50)
        SET @hotel_level = 'Bronze'; 
    ELSE IF (@rating >= 4.50 AND @rating < 4.80)
        SET @hotel_level = 'Silver';
    ELSE IF (@rating >= 4.80 AND @rating < 4.90)
        SET @hotel_level = 'Gold';
    ELSE IF @rating >= 4.90
        SET @hotel_level = 'Platinum';

    RETURN @hotel_level;
END
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yWWE.png)
[Result of storage function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yenjg.png)

I created this function in MySQL first and it worked. I tried to create the same in SQL Server and that's when something went wrong.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted tabular text

Comment: Remove the SELECT @rating = rating  FROM Hotels;   You are passing the value

Comment: Furthermore, I hate seeing things like this in code.   I tend to use a generic TIER table and JOIN to determine the results

Comment: I think this should have been posted here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: BTW: I think the translation from MySQL (you did) sucks, but you did not share the MySQL code, sot that's only a guess..... 

Comment: You debug SQL the same as any other code, you copy the SQL out of your function and run it stand alone in SSMS, and you add selects/prints to understand what is happening/not happening at each stage of your code.

Comment: No @Luuk , broken code is [not ready for review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) until it's fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on my comment.

Imagine `@Tier` is an actual table with various tiers for various reasons.   This structure can also be used for conditional aggregations and groupings.

**Example**

```
Declare @Tier Table ([Tier_Grp] varchar(50),[Tier_R1] money,[Tier_R2] money,[Tier_Desc] varchar(50))  Insert Into @Tier Values 
 ('Hotel Rating',0,4.1,'Blue')
,('Hotel Rating',4.1,4.5,'Bronze')
,('Hotel Rating',4.5,4.8,'Silver')
,('Hotel Rating',4.8,4.9,'Gold')
,('Hotel Rating',4.9,99,'Platnum')
 
Declare @Data Table ([ID] int,[Rating] decimal(10,2))  Insert Into @Data Values 
 (9965,4.7)
,(9966,4.88)
 
Select A.* 
      ,B.Tier_Desc
 From @Data A
 Join @Tier B on Tier_Grp='Hotel Rating' 
             and Rating>=Tier_R1 and Rating<Tier_R2
```

**Results**

```
ID      Rating  Tier_Desc
9965    4.70    Silver
9966    4.88    Gold
```

Answer (score 0):

The rating is passed as a parameter to you function (`@rating`). So there is no need to get that value from the table Hotels in your function:

```
SELECT @rating = rating
    FROM Hotels;
```

When you leave out this line, because there is no need to change the value of the parameter `@rating` in your function, your function works as expected.